# Authorize.net CIM getting CVC error while it should'nt be

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I've installed this [Authorize.net CIM module](https://marketplace.magento.com/rootways-module-authorizecim.html), and installed before other Authorize.net CIM modules, i have an issue when trying to pay with this module in backend.
I edited an order and choosed the Authorize.net CIM module and entered credit card crediantials, and entered a correct CVC but i got this error

[image]

```
Please enter a valid credit card verification number.
```

When entering card number, card expiration date and CVC, there's an ajax call to this URL

```
https://domain.com/admin/sales/order_create/loadBlock/key/17a31e8ff3761d677a591560419237f0bf2971735ade601f87e08526b6571ec6/block/card_validation?isAjax=true
```

With response

```
{"message":""}
```

Can someone help me to found the block "card_validation" and how to fix the issue related to CVC?

PS: i disabled all other Authorize.net CIM modules.
Magento version : 2.2.4
Production mode for Authorize.net
Developer mode for Magento

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disabling the Authorize.net other module